Playwright does not install in Visual Studio Code
I installed Visual Studio Code and included JavaScript and PHP cause I had a training course in it.
Now I need Playwright/Cucumber for my job.
There seem to be two ways of installing it, either adding the extension from the list or using npm i, npm playwright install in the VS Terminal.
npm didn't work, so I also installed node.js and apparently it is there when I find out the version using Windows prompt.
I installed the Playwright extension the way it was described on the website.
https://playwright.dev/docs/getting-started-vscode
But npm still cannot be found.
What is missing and what kind of info do you need?
Thank you.
David
It said it needed to be restarted which I did, how do I find out all my extensions?
I installed it in a folder with data in it already:
.github
.vscode
reports
src
package.json etc...
Playwright Test for VSCode
v1.1.2
Microsoft
microsoft.com
672,906
(28)
Run Playwright Test tests in Visual Studio Code.
Disable
Uninstall
This extension is enabled globally.
npm : Die Benennung "npm" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern
enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1

npm init playwright@latest --yes -- --quiet --browser=chromium --brow ...

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException





node --version
v20.13.1
npm --version
10.8.0

I'm confused. How did you get the npm version that you can't run?

I installed node.js from here: https://nodejs.org/en/

I'd use nvm rather than direct node install, for starters. Node and npm should install together. I'd also start by installing and running it without vscode, then worry about vscode later. You can always run it from the vscode terminal/shell if all else fails. The process, commands run and system details here are rather disorganized. I suggest [edit]ing the question to add clarity. Step by step, OS details, commands, output, exact errors and messages. Output of where npm, where node etc. Error message should be in English, since this is an English-only site. Thanks.

I don't know about nvm. I had VS Code already installed for over a year.
When I started the question there were two text boxes, when I submitted both were integrated into one. Probably better to post screenshots rather than the contents of the screenshot.
npm : The name "npm" was not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, a function, a script file or an executable program. Check the spelling of the name or whether the path is correct (if included) and repeat the process. In line:1 Character:1
